# How to exit script on failed conditionals (Concrete Exception in this case) before try/except happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, exit

I have a Python script that looks like this:

```
import discord, asyncio, sys

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    async for msg in client.logs_from(client.get_channel(None), limit=1):
        try:
            await client.send_message(msg.channel, "test")
        except: 
            sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)

client.run('ClientTokenHere')
```

This raises an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` because the `get_channel()` is trying to get the channel id from `None` (`None` is the `id` but it should be an integer).

But the Python script displays the Attribute Error, and then just hangs on the terminal without exiting the script, I'm guessing because it doesn't even reach the `try`/`except` part of the script where I have `sys.exit(0)`. How can I make it so that the script exits completely to where it displays the text input area for typing in commands in the command line, without me having to Ctrl+C out of the script manually when I get this error?

Comment: Add an additional `try ... except AttributeError` to exit in the right place.

Comment: Thanks @Cfreak, that worked